# How to slice column values in Python pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this-

```
element id  year    month   days    tmax    tmin
0   MX17004 2010    1   d1          NaN      NaN
1   MX17004 2010    1   d10         NaN      NaN
2   MX17004 2010    1   d11         NaN      NaN
3   MX17004 2010    1   d12         NaN      NaN
4   MX17004 2010    1   d13         NaN      NaN
```

where I want to further break days column like this
**

```
days
1
10
11
12
13
```

**
I have tried a couple of ways, but not successful in getting the output. Can someone please help or some clue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By using `str` slice

```
df.days=df.days.str[1:]
df
Out[759]: 
   element       id  year  month days  tmax  tmin
0        0  MX17004  2010      1    1   NaN   NaN
1        1  MX17004  2010      1   10   NaN   NaN
2        2  MX17004  2010      1   11   NaN   NaN
3        3  MX17004  2010      1   12   NaN   NaN
4        4  MX17004  2010      1   13   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: @DipanjanSaha yw~ :-) , If that help , can you consider accept it ?

Comment: yes, please. Would you also recommend some good books/youtube channel/resources for Pandas mostly for data cleansing?

Comment: @DipanjanSaha I will recommend  https://www.amazon.com/dp/1784393878/?tag=stackoverflow17-20

Answer (score 0):

Use `extract` with regex:

```
df['days'] = df.days.str.extract('d(\d+)', expand=False)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   element       id  year  month days  tmax  tmin
0        0  MX17004  2010      1    1   NaN   NaN
1        1  MX17004  2010      1   10   NaN   NaN
2        2  MX17004  2010      1   11   NaN   NaN
3        3  MX17004  2010      1   12   NaN   NaN
4        4  MX17004  2010      1   13   NaN   NaN
```